# PHPExcel outputing different files in different servers

Tags: php, phpexcel

Recently I had to change my application to another server and everything is OK, but the xlsx files using PHPExcel.
I compared a good file from the previous server with a file from the new one. Since xlsx is just a zipped file, I unpacked them to comparison. There was no difference.
Then, I compared them on notepad++ and the binary string on both is different.
I suppose there is something to do with encoding but I'm really lost here.

**Useful information**

Headers:

```
->setRawHeader("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT")
->setRawHeader("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT")
->setRawHeader("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate")
->setRawHeader("Pragma: no-cache")
->setRawHeader("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
->setRawHeader("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file}\"")
->setRawHeader("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
```

Saving:

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($excel);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

- <s>There is no trash output before the file byte stream;</s> BOMs
- Both servers have the same code;
- The generated file on the new server is throwing invalid file error on excel;
- Both servers are running windows and apache;
- $file is set previously;

Thank you!

Comment: Without having any clue what the difference is, this question is absolutely impossible to answer.... perhaps a difference between 32-bit and 64-bit platforms? Can both files be loaded in MS Excel?

Comment: Hey Mark! I followed a lot of your tips here about this in other questions, thank you already!
I'll try to put the iles here.

Comment: Oh no, there is a BOM at the beginning...
Notepad++ was not showing it, just realized the BOM was there trying to paste the beginning of the files here.
Sorry, i'll try to remove it now.

Comment: Any tips on removing it from the generated file?

Comment: If there's a BOM header being injected into the Excel file, then you need to identify which script file has been saved with a BOM header

Comment: Can't find the file on my project...
What is the possible cause of that? How does this relates to chanching to another server?

Comment: I can think of no reason why it should apply on one server and not another.

Comment: I found file containing a BOM, for no apparent reason it happened on the server change.
Thanks for the help!
Do you mind writing an answer so I can mark it as answered?